# PGbouncer não conecta via serviço no windows

Tags: delphi, postgresql, zeos, psql

Instalei o pgbouncer como serviço no windows 10 usando:

```
pgbouncer.exe --regservice   <pgbouncer.ini>
```

Colocando o caminho do ini e a partir da pasta onde está o exe do pgbouncer.
O serviço é instalado normalmente e consigo iniciar ele pelo gerenciador de serviços do windows.

Porém quando vou conectar usando o zeos no delphi ele diz:

```
SQL Error: ERROR: No such user: postgres
```

Ocorre o mesmo erro usando o psql.

Se eu iniciar o pgbouncer via cmd usando:

```
pgbouncer pgbouncer.ini
```

Dá tudo certo. Só o serviço que não funciona.

Comment: me parece algo com o usuário que está rodando o serviço... tente defini-lo na aba de logon na janela de propriedades do serviço do windows

Comment: @RovannLinhalis tentei como dissestes e não consegui conectar. O interessante é que o único usuário que ele aceita é: **pgbouncer**, contudo a senha (que tentei várias) ele diz que é inválida: `SQL Error: ERROR: Auth failed`

Comment: Consegui dar mais um passo

Adicionei: **auth_user=postgres** no pgbouncer.ini

Ficando assim:

`[databases]

template1 = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=novo auth_user=postgres`

Agora quando conecto ele reconhece que o usuario postgres existe mas agora diz que:

`SQL Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Answer (score 0):

Todo o problema é devido a **versão**. Instalei a versão: **1.6.1** 64bits e funcionou.